# Generating a list of Start Times and End Times in Java

Tags: java

I need to generate a list of Start Times and End Times in Java such that, End Time is always greater than Start Time and the difference between Start Time and End Time must be maximum of 5 hours.

Time Format can be of either 24 hours or 12 hours.

I tried this code but the difference between Start Time and End Time criteria  was not satisfied for all start times and End Times:

```
         String myTime = "07:00:00";
         SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
         Date d = df.parse(myTime); 
         Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal1.setTime(d);
         Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
         cal2.setTime(d);
         int i=10;

         List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
         List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<String>();


         while(i<50)
         {

             cal1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, i);
             String Start_Time = df.format(cal1.getTime());
             cal2.add(Calendar.SECOND, i);
             String End_Time = df.format(cal2.getTime());
             list3.add(Start_Time);
             list4.add(End_Time);
             i=i+1;
         }
            File file = new File("output9.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
            System.setOut(ps);
            for (int j = 0,k=0;j < list3.size()&&k<list4.size(); j++,k++) {
                String value3 = list3.get(j);
                String value4 = list4.get(k);
                System.out.println("\n");
                System.out.printf("%s%s%s",value3," ",value4);
            }
```

Could anyone please help me how to do it?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your Problem is in the addition of your startTimes. You add n Minutes to the starttime, but only add this amount to the seconds of the endtime.

So you schould change the following int he `while`:

```
cal1.add(Calendar.MINUTE, i);
String Start_Time = df.format(cal1.getTime());
cal2.add(Calendar.MINUTE, i); // add this line
cal2.add(Calendar.SECOND, i);
String End_Time = df.format(cal2.getTime());
```

If you want real random ranges, you could achieve this by setting the start to a random time, save this as a String into your array and add then an amount of time between 0 and 5 hours and add this to your end array.

EDIT example for random ranges

```
Random rand = new Random();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

List<String> startTimes = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> endTimes = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7 + rand.nextInt(7)); // Starting at 07:00:00
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, rand.nextInt(60));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, rand.nextInt(60));
    String Start_Time = df.format(calendar.getTime());

    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, rand.nextInt(5));
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, rand.nextInt(60));
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, rand.nextInt(60));
    String End_Time = df.format(calendar.getTime());
    startTimes.add(Start_Time);
    endTimes.add(End_Time);
}
```

This would generate 50 startTimes from 7 to 14 and endTimes a maximum of 5 hours longer.
Example:

```
[13:38:56, 08:32:57, 08:50:15, 07:10:49, 13:48:06]
[13:45:53, 08:36:29, 12:16:35, 11:19:06, 17:19:36]
```